# Combining spiders in Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

Is it possible to create a spider which inherits/uses functionality from two base spiders?

I'm trying to scrape various sites and I've noticed that in many instances the site provides a sitemap but this just points to category/listing type pages, not 'real' content. Because of this I'm having to use the CrawlSpider (pointing to the website root) instead but this is pretty inefficient as it crawls through all pages including a lot of junk.

What I would like to do is something like this:

1. Start my Spider which is a subclass of SitemapSpider and pass each response to the parse_items method.
2. In parse_items test if the page contains 'real' content
3. If it does then process it, if not pass the response to the
   CrawlSpider (actually my subclass of CrawlSpider) to process
4. CrawlSpider then looks for links in the page, say 2 levels deep and
   processes them

Is this possible? I realise that I could copy and paste the code from the CrawlSpider into my spider but this seems like a poor design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I decided to just extend sitemap spider and lift some of the code from the crawl spider as it was simpler that trying to deal with multiple inheritance issues so basically:

```
class MySpider(SitemapSpider):
   def __init__(self, **kw):
      super(MySpider, self).__init__(**kw)
      self.link_extractor = LxmlLinkExtractor()

   def parse(self, response):
      # perform item extraction etc
      ...
      links = self.link_extractor.extract_links(response)
      for link in links:
        yield Request(link.url, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Hello toby, I am trying to do something similar to what you had described, could you provide me with some snippets on how you solved the problem.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider, CrawlSpider, Rule

class MySpider(SitemapSpider, CrawlSpider):
    name = "myspider"
    rules = ( Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('', )), callback='parse_item', follow=True), )
    sitemap_rules = [ ('/', 'parse_item'), ]
    sitemap_urls = ['http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # Do your stuff here
        ...
        # Return to CrawlSpider that will crawl them
        yield from self.parse(response)
```

This way, Scrapy will start with the urls in the sitemap, then follow all links within each url.

Source: [Multiple inheritance in scrapy spiders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797762/multiple-inheritance-in-scrapy-spiders)

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit as usual, the only thing you have to be careful is that the base spiders usually override the basic methods `start_requests` and `parse`. The other thing to point out is that `CrawlSpider` will get links form every response that goes through [`_parse_response`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/spiders/crawl.py#L63).

Answer (score 0):

Setting a low value do `DEPTH_LIMIT` should be a way to manage the fact that `CrawlSpider` will get links for every response that goes through `_parse_response` (after reviewing the original question, it was alrady proposed).