# Scrapy SitemapSpider - How can I add process_links functionality to modify links before they're downloaded like with CrawlSpiders?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

## The Overview

I'm using a `SitemapSpider` to crawl nested sitemaps of a site. On the second level sitemaps there are product page urls that I only want to retrieve the endings of (example: .../product-detail/outdoor-solutions-terracotta-wall-fountain/{**1927940**} ) and substitute in the api version of the product link (json) instead of the downloader requesting the actual product page (html). I know this functionality is possible with `CrawlSpider`'s ability to provide detailed [Rules](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule). I'm particularly interested in having the ability to use the Rule's `process_links` function on the matching product urls, so that I modify the links in the sitemap before the page source is downloaded. That way I can avoid having to first download the actual product page before submitting an additional request per product to get the underlying structured json representation of the data.

From what I see in the Scrapy documentation though, the [sitemap_rules](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.SitemapSpider.sitemap_rules) property of SitemapSpider only offers the ability to provide a callback and doesn't extend the `process_links` functionality that `CrawlSpider's Rules` do.

## The Question

So, my question is, how can I extend the SitemapSpider to allow for the ability to process/change certain links before they're sent to the downloader?

Below is how I imagine the SitemapSpider operating. Would it be as simple as subclassing the Spider like `class ExampleSpider(SitemapSpider, CrawlSpider):`?

```py
    api_url = 'https://www.example.com/api/v1/product/{}?fields=all'
    
    class ExampleSpider(SitemapSpider):
        name = 'example'
        allowed_domains = ['example.com']
        sitemap_urls = ['https://www.example.com/sitemap/siteindex.xml']
        # this will follow all the productSitemaps (ie. productSitemap1.xml, productSitemap2.xml)
        sitemap_follow = ['/productSitemap'] 
        
        # this is currently what I want to override or extend, so it acts like CrawlSpider.Rules
        sitemap_rules = [('/product/', 'parse_product')]
        # this is how I envision it working
        ideal_sitemap_rules = [('/product/', process_links=lambda link: api_url.format(link.rsplit('/', 1)[1]), callback='parse_product')]
    
        def parse_product(self, response):
            print('now response.json() should contain the product json')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like scrapy middlewares can do the trick here (https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html)

Specifically look at the request scheduled signal https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#request-scheduled

Comment: I don't believe middleware is needed here, but I could be wrong. Regardless though, I've seen the documentation, what I'm struggling with is a practical implementation.

Comment: You are right @CaffeinatedMike, the Middleware can be a overkill here.

In your case and looking at the question again you can inherit both classes and use both the sitemap rules and custom rules for the API calls:

`ideal_sitemap_rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/(.*?)/product/(.*?)']), process_value=lambda link: api_url.format(link.rsplit('/', 1)[1], 'parse_product')`

As a reference check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797762/multiple-inheritance-in-scrapy-spiders

Comment: I saw that question before posting mine, but the only difference between what I'm looking to do and what the other OP did is the fact that I don't want to request/download the html version of the page before it's processed by the `Rule`. I'm looking to do the opposite, I need the url to be pre-processed by the rule (so the url can be rewritten as the api url) before being requested/downloaded.